# FHIR Server Installation

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-playbook

I want to install my own FHIR server on ubuntu machine with the help of this link. [smart-on-fhir/installer](https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/installer)

But when i run this command `sudo ansible-playbook -c local -i 'localhost,' -vvvv site.yml`, it gives following error. Please give some idea, what is wrong with this.

**Error**

```
root@s5ubuntu-desktop:~/bk/installer/provisioning# sudo ansible-playbook -c local -i 'localhost,' -vvvv site.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/root/bk/installer/provisioning/roles/linux-machine/tasks/main.yml': line 161, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Configure MySQL user
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/root/bk/installer/provisioning/roles/linux-machine/tasks/main.yml': line 161, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Configure MySQL user
  ^ here

root@s5ubuntu-desktop:~/bk/installer/provisioning
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure that you are using the latest Ansible version by installing Ansible via `pip install ansible`. Even so I don't think that is the problem here.

You should also check that the module requirement `MySQLdb` is installed on the target system.

> Requires the MySQLdb Python package on the remote host. For Ubuntu, this is as easy as apt-get install python-mysqldb. (See apt.) For CentOS/Fedora, this is as easy as yum install MySQL-python. (See yum.) [mysql_user_module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html)

There are lots of things in the repository I find strange. The error `no action detected in task` indicates, as I might have already guessed, that there is no action defined for the task. The failing task defines `task name`, `tags`, `module` which is an unusual order, but as all the tasks in the repository are defined like that, that does not seem to be the problem here.

If the tasks still fails with latest Ansible version and MySQLdb package installed open an [issue](https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/installer/issues) on the github project page.